# create a shortcut key for new Text documents(.txt),how to edit the regedit,and the (.reg) file?

Tags: windows, windows-shell, regedit

question detail：

when you right click  ,show the right menu,and then new →  new Text documents

after that the (NewTextdocuments.txt) will be created .

but question is that i want to use the shortcut keys(for example：crtl + Alt + N ) to complete the action above

### i just know the following

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew\Hot Keys]

"Key Modifiers"=hex:03,c0,00,00
"Virtual Key"=hex:4e,00,00,00
```

---

Comment: I don't know where you got that registry setting from, but it is complete nonsense. It looks like somebody took IME settings and copied them to the ShellNew key.

Comment: i know that  the shortcut keys(ctrl + shift + N ) is to new folder,but why i can't use the other shortcut keys to  new Text documents(or other file),this is the question!

Comment: That shortcut is hard-coded into the system. This is not a programming question.